# Translate a 3d pyramid on openGl?

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I have this code right here which makes a pyramid 3d. Also it displays a scale and rotation on x,y,z. My main problem is the translation, like it walking in y from -180 to 180 coordinates and doing rotation together. So fair just move from (0,0,0) to (-180,0,0) and it stays in that point. I want to start from -180 and to going on 180 (to run the pyramid ).

```
                              |
                              |
                              |
         /_\  - - - - - - - - | - - - - - - - - - > /_\  
       ---|-------------------|----------------------|-------
        -180                  |                     180    
                              |
                              |
                              |
```

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <cmath>

struct point3D { double x, y, z; };

struct matrix3x3
{
    double  a, b, c,
            d, e, f,
            g, h, i;
};

point3D C[5];

double ANGLEY = 0, ANGLEZ = 0;

void set_identity_matrix(matrix3x3 &m)
{
    m.a = 1; m.b = 0; m.c = 0;
    m.d = 0; m.e = 1; m.f = 0;
    m.g = 0; m.h = 0; m.i = 1;
}

void mult(matrix3x3 m, point3D &p)
{
    point3D temp;
    temp.x = m.a * p.x + m.b * p.y + m.c * p.z;
    temp.y = m.d * p.x + m.e * p.y + m.f * p.z;
    temp.z = m.g * p.x + m.h * p.y + m.i * p.z;
    p = temp;
}

void rotateY(point3D &p, double degrees)
{
    matrix3x3 temp;
    set_identity_matrix(temp);
    double sinTheta = sin(degrees * M_PI / 180);
    double cosTheta = cos(degrees * M_PI / 180);
    temp.a = cosTheta;
    temp.c = sinTheta;
    temp.g = -sinTheta;
    temp.i = cosTheta;
    mult(temp, p);
}

void rotateZ(point3D &p, double degrees)
{
    matrix3x3 temp;
    set_identity_matrix(temp);
    double sinTheta = sin(degrees * M_PI / 180);
    double cosTheta = cos(degrees * M_PI / 180);
    temp.a = cosTheta;
    temp.b = -sinTheta;
    temp.d = sinTheta;
    temp.e = cosTheta;
    mult(temp, p);
}


void draw_line(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2d(x1, y1);
    glVertex2d(x2, y2);
    glEnd();
}

void setup_pyramid()
{
    C[0].x = -0.5; C[0].y = -0.5; C[0].z = -0.5;
    C[1].x = -0.5; C[1].y = -0.5; C[1].z = 0.5;
    C[2].x = 0.5;  C[2].y = -0.5; C[2].z = 0.5;
    C[3].x = 0.5;  C[3].y = -0.5; C[3].z = -0.5;
    C[4].x = 0.0;  C[4].y = 0.5;  C[4].z = 0.0;

}

void scale_pyramid(double s)
{
    int i;

    for( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    {
        C[i].x *= s;
        C[i].y *= s;
        C[i].z *= s;
    }
}

void draw_pyramid()
{
    int i;

    for( i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
    {   
        draw_line(C[i].x, C[i].y, C[(i + 1) % 4].x, C[(i + 1) % 4]. y);
        draw_line(C[i].x, C[i].y, C[4].x, C[4]. y);  
    }
      
}


void draw_axes()
{
    glPushAttrib(GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS);
    glColor3ub(0, 0, 0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2d(-240, 0);
    glVertex2d( 240, 0);
    glVertex2d(0, -180);
    glVertex2d(0, 180);
    glEnd();
    glPopAttrib();
}

void display()
{
   int i;
   float k;
    
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    draw_axes();
    
    
    for( k=-180.0; k < 180; k++)
    
    glTranslated ( k, 0.0  ,0.0 );
    
    for( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    
        rotateZ(C[i], -ANGLEZ);
         
    
    
    for( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )

        rotateY(C[i], -ANGLEY);
   
    glColor3ub(0, 0, 255);
    draw_pyramid();
  
   
    for( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    
        rotateY(C[i], ANGLEY);
        
    
    
    for( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
 
        rotateZ(C[i], ANGLEZ);
        
    glTranslated ( k+1, -0.0  ,0.0 );

   
   
    ANGLEY += 1;
    ANGLEZ += 1;

    glFlush();
}

void timer(int value)
{
    display();
    glutTimerFunc(1000.0 / 90.0, timer, 0);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_SINGLE);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Lab");
    gluOrtho2D(-240, 240, -180, 180);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    timer(0);
    setup_pyramid();
    scale_pyramid(100);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Each frame is rendered from scratch. What you want is to translate it -150 on the first frame, -149 on the second frame, -148 on the third frame, etc. Can you do that?

Comment: [`glTranslate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTranslate.xml)